# "Stoker" - sound design moves background to foreground

Tags: sound-design, film

I've just come back from seeing Stoker - what a great film. Very strong, and potent storytelling. One of the features was a forensic-style magnification of detail, and lots of space and time for elements to settle in.

You become acutely aware of the background elements, and it's very interesting hearing these mixed UP, very, very loud - as the character hears with great precision and accuracy, the audience are invited to engage in that experience too.

One of the most striking uses I thought was in the woods scene - the woodpecker sound was just spine chilling (it's just a woodpecker, I know), and there were these slightly processed bird calls that sounded dischordant and alien. They kept on getting louder, and louder, and louder...until you realise you're in a horror context. Then they stop.

Powerful filmmaking, great sound design.

If you've seen it, post your thoughts

T

Comment: That sounds cool... (but it isn't a question!) :)

Comment: That would be great if you could rewrite this in question format pointing out the exact point you are curious about, or points that would be great to hear some apporaches, so that a discussion can be built around and some tangible results beyond opinions can be achieved.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a question

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely agree - great film and fantastic sound.

I especially loved the sound of the eggshell cracking.

Answer (score 0):

Was already 'stoked' about watching this ;) now im even more excited!

Answer (score 0):

Such an excellent film!  I loved the opening sequence; the way the foreground sounds froze with the picture but the background elements continued to play was really powerful, both on its own stand-alone merit as a scene, and in the manner in which it introduces you to the way certain sound elements will be isolated and enhanced throughout the film.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is one of those marriages between picture and sound that is sublime. One it's not above the other. They just complement each other. Like in a dance, when one element is ready to shine the other just supports it while they're dancing. 
It is a pleasure to see and it is a pleasure to hear.
EG

Answer (score 0):

Funny thing: I've just finished watching it for the second time! And...hell yes! Unfortunately, I didn't have the chance to see it in a cinema here in Prague, and I have to admit that I didn't want to wait for BluRay so I downloaded it (nasty!). This morning, I found it in a store between discounted DVDs. I enjoyed 5.1 at home and got even more sad that I didn't see it in the cinema. 
I agree with Tom. The woodpecker/birds scene was very well done and the overall final mix was something special. It sure would be exciting to work with ambiences/background sounds like that! Thank you for mentioning it, Tom!

Answer (score 0):

Mic Macs (from director of Amelie) is a quality film with some excellent sound design. Also Wall•E ia often rated highly for its sound design, they involved Burtt in that and he got a little crazy (watch the extras!)